# SQL parser error describe tables/databases in CnosDB

Tags: database, cnosdb

When i run

```
describe databases test1;
```

I get an error

```
public ❯ describe databases test1;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected tables/databases, found: databases"}
public ❯
```

I followed the instructions to run it, but it didn't work, how should i use it correctly?

Comment: are you saying the error message should be updated to reflect the expected key word?

Comment: I don't know if I did it wrong or there is something wrong with the prompt

Comment: It's possible that the error message is a bug/typo in the error message. It's also possible that the documentation is outdated and needs to be updated to reflect the correct syntax. Regardless, the correct syntax for describing a database in CnosDB is `describe database test1`

Comment: it appears you have raised a bug for this: https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/issues/1160